# SBT make one project compile with only one version of scala

Tags: scala, sbt

In sbt with a multiproject setup, is there a way to make sure that one of the projects compiles with only version of Scala. Eg

```
/foo (scala-2.13.8)
/bar (scala-2.12.15, scala-2.13.8, scala-3.1.1)
/baz (scala-2.12.15, scala-2.13.8, scala-3.1.1)
```

So basically I want `bar` and `baz` to cross compile where as `foo` to compile only for `scala-2.13.8`

Is this possible? What would the build config look like?

Comment: it depends if you have inter dependencies between projects

Answer (score 3):

It is possible if you don't have dependencies from `baz` or `bar` to `foo`.

For example, the following `build.sbt` will only compile `foo` with version `2.13.8` when you call `sbt +compile`

```
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.8"
ThisBuild / crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.12.15", "2.13.8", "3.1.1")

val foo = project.settings(
  crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.13.8")
)
val bar = project
val baz = project
```